# Movie player sample and probblem with execute

Tags: android, sd-card, movie, sample

I am new in Android. I want to lunch example from this page: http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/displaying-list-of-video-files-stored.html

I copy code from there to my classes, create avd with sd card, and copy on sd card some movies in mp4 format. When I want to start application I get communication with error:
"The application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again".
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Maybe with filename is something wrong? I am only want to lunch this project. Can anyone try lunch this code and tell me what I must change. Thx a lot. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrong named my class and in AndroidManifest I must change some data. Now all things works.